# airflow SSH operator error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: kubernetes, ssh, airflow, amazon-emr

airflow 1.10.10  
minikube 1.22.0  
amazon emr

I am running airflow on kubernetes(minikube).
Dags are synced from github.
spark-submit on Amazon EMR as a CLI mode.

In order to do that, I attach EMR pem key.
So, I get pem key from AWS S3 while ExtraInitContainer is getting image awscli and mount the volume at airlfow/sshpem

error is reported when I make a connection from airflow WebUI as
"con_type": "ssh"
"key_file": "/opt/sshepm/emr.pem"

```
SSH operator error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/airflow/sshpem/emr.pem'
```

it is there. I think it is related to some PATH or permission issue since I get emr.pem on ExtraInitContainer and it's permission was root. Although I temporarily changed a user as 1000:1000 there is some issue airflow WebUI can't get this directory while getting a key.

Full log is below

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
    > "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py",
    > line 108, in execute
    >     with self.ssh_hook.get_conn() as ssh_client:   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py",
    > line 194, in get_conn
    >     client.connect(**connect_kwargs)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py",
    > line 446, in connect
    >     passphrase,   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py",
    > line 677, in _auth
    >     key_filename, pkey_class, passphrase   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py",
    > line 586, in _key_from_filepath
    >     key = klass.from_private_key_file(key_path, password)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py",
    > line 235, in from_private_key_file
    >     key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py",
    > line 55, in __init__
    >     self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py",
    > line 175, in _from_private_key_file
    >     data = self._read_private_key_file("RSA", filename, password)   File
    > "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py",
    > line 307, in _read_private_key_file
    >     with open(filename, "r") as f: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/airflow/sshpem/emr-pa.pem'
    > 
    > During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    > 
    > Traceback (most recent call last):   File
    > "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py",
    > line 979, in _run_raw_task
    >     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)   File "/opt/airflow/class101-airflow/plugins/operators/emr_ssh_operator.py",
    > line 107, in execute
    >     super().execute(context)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py",
    > line 177, in execute
    >     raise AirflowException("SSH operator error: {0}".format(str(e))) airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: SSH operator error: [Errno 2] No
    > such file or directory: '/opt/airflow/sshpem/emr-pa.pem' [2021-07-14
    > 05:40:31,624] Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=test_staging,
    > task_id=extract_categories_from_mongo, execution_date=20210712T190000,
    > start_date=20210714T054031, end_date=20210714T054031 [2021-07-14
    > 05:40:36,303] Task exited with return code 1
```

airflow home: /opt/airflow 
dags : /opt/airflow//dags 
pemkey : /opt/sshpem/ 
airflow.cfg: /opt/airflow 
airflow_env:
export PATH="/home/airflow/.local/bin:$PATH"

my yaml file

```
airflow: 
   image: 
     repository: airflow
   executor: KubernetesExecutor
   extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: sshpem
      mountPath: /opt/airflow/sshpem
   extraVolumes:
    - name: sshpem
      emptyDir: {}
scheduler:
    extraInitContainers:
    - name: emr-key-file-download
      image: amazon/aws-cli
      command: [
        "sh",
        "-c",
        "aws s3 cp s3://mykeyfile/path.my.pem&& \
        chown -R 1000:1000 /opt/airflow/sshpem/"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/airflow/sshpem
          name: sshpem
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using KubernetesExecutor or CeleryExecutor?

If the former, then you have to make sure the extra init container is added to the pod_template you are using (tasks in KubernetesExecutor) run as separate PODs.

If the latter, you should make sure the extra init container is also added for workers, not only for scheduler).

BTW. Airflow 1.10 reached end-of-life on June 17th, 2021 and it will not receive even critical security fixes. You can watch our talk from the recent Airflow Summit "Keep your Airflow Secure" - https://airflowsummit.org/sessions/2021/panel-airflow-security/ to learn why it is important to upgrade to Airflow 2.

Comment: I am so happy that one of airflow contributor has replied to my question. While your answer is pretty clear but please bare my extra questions.

Comment: I edited a question with yaml file that I don't get clear when you talk about adding this ExtrainitContainer(awscli image) to the scheduler. many many thanks!

Comment: In your example it's exactly what I suspected. You are using KubernetesExecutor, which means that each task is run in it's own Pod. In the example abobe your init container is only runnig for scheduler - you should configure your pod template file for Kubernetes Executor to also run this init container and map the file to inside the container running Airflow https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/kubernetes.html#pod-template-file

Comment: while airflow WebUI fails, when I run a airflow test command on airflow pod scheduler container, it goes success.

Comment: my airflow version is 1.10.11 which I don't think your suggestion (pod_template_file supported from 1.10.12) applies. So I guess I go and upgrade airflow to 1.10.12 and write another pod_template_file.yaml and locate that file SOMEWHERE ? or include that template inside main.yaml file . Am I getting write? I really need this since I am struggling for +10 hours so far. You are more than appreciated already though!

Comment: Well. If you install "cncf.kubernetes" backport providers, you could use pod_template_file. But the "backport providers" stopped being released in March and there were many fixes since then in "cncf.kubernetes" provider that governs it. And see my comment above - the 1.10 is not maintained nor supported. I could recommend you stop looosing time now, but migrate to Airflow  2 ASAP.

Comment: That is great help Mr.Potiuk. I will move on to Airflow2.0 soon.